# Error with validate

Tags: 7, hooks

```
 function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {

            if ($form['#form_id'] == 'article_node_form') {         
              $form['#validate'][] = '_mymodule_test_validation';
                }
    }

    function mymodule_test_validation($form, &$form_state) {
        dsm("hello");
    }
```

Why is not printed the word "hello"??  What is my error in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see right way of doing form alter below

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form_id = $form['form_id']['#value'];
  if ($form_id == "article_node_form") {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_test_validation';
  }
}

function mymodule_test_validation($form, &$form_state) {
  if(($form_state['values']['test_field']) == ''){
    form_set_error('test_field', t('You must select a name for this group of  settings.'));
  }
}
```

FYI, [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), [Form API reference #validate](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#validate) and [`form_set_error()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7)

Comment: In my case if I put $form_id == "article_ndoe_form"  appears the next error:  Notice: Undefined variable: form_id  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm going to update in your answer the code worked for me.  Thanks for your help.